# NetStream http Video not playing on IOS device

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I am trying to play a video on iPad, my code is below :

```
public function init_RTMP():void
    {
        videoURL = "http://rest************_iphone_high.mp4";           
        vid = new Video();

        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onConnectionStatus);
        nc.connect(null);           
    }

    private function onConnectionStatus(e:NetStatusEvent):void
    {
        if (e.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success")
        {
            trace("Creating NetStream");
            netStreamObj = new NetStream(nc);
            metaListener = new Object();
            metaListener.onMetaData = received_Meta;
            netStreamObj.client = metaListener;

            netStreamObj.play(videoURL);
            vid.attachNetStream(netStreamObj);
            addChild(vid);
        }
    }
```

when i play it on my system it is working fine, but when i create a IOS app of it and installs on device, it shows white blank screen.

If anyone have same problem or any idea please share with me.

Comment: There could be many reasons why this is happening. Assuming you are building your app with AIR, try adding something else to the stage before trying to load the video. This way you can rule out the possibility of the app not launching. Then load your video with a button tap. Check your connectivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As VC.One pointed out, AIR for iOS does not play most (but not all, it will occasionally play a very specific encode type) h.264 encoded videos. There are three solutions:

1. As VC.One said, you encode as FLV. Doing this is not good and I would not recommend it. FLV is not hardware accelerated (unless things have changed recently and I have not seen the updates) and will run entirely off the CPU meaning your app will run slowly and the app will eat battery much quicker than normal.
2. Use [`StageWebView`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html), in which case you just plug in the URL to the video and it will play the video using the native video player. This has the down side in that you cannot skint he player and you cannot control it. Once it begins playing, you have no control over it except for unloading the page. This works very well, however, and is fairly easy to implement, though the video will appear on top of the stage (it is **not** in the `Display List`).
3. The last option is to use [`StageVideo`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html). This will play videos using the native framework, so you can easily play h.264 *and* it will be hardware accelerated. Additionally, this is just a NetStream player so you have full control over it. And best yet, it has no chrome so you can build a player around the video screen. However, like StageWebView, StageVideo is **not** in the `Display List`. But unlike StageWebView, it is rendered directly on the stage, *below* everything else. So the app itself will cover the video. You can get around this by creating a class to mask your app around the video, but it is incredibly difficult to properly pull off. It took me about 12 hours to create my StageVideo player and the masking class, plus another half day later on fixing issues with the masking class and how it handles DPI changes (hint: do NOT set `applicationDPI` if you are using Flex)

As always, make sure your AIR SDK is up to date as well. 3.5-3.7 have all added a ton of new features and bug fixes for iOS applications so updating to AIR 3.7 might actually solve or make your issue less of a problem (I don't think it will, but it is always worth a shot, right?)

Answer (score 0):

See this link:

> [Netstream video not playing on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032141/netstream-video-not-playing-on-ipad)

Basically it was fixed by encoding the video file as FLV not MP4.

Comment: Even on http? or just playing the file locally?

Comment: Hi sorry but i've been away from S.O... Did you find a solution OK in the end?