# Actionscript netStream play mp4 with ios

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, mp4

I'm trying to play a video from an app using Flash Builder 4.7, AIRSDK 31.0 and ios 12.

```
private function init():void{
    holder.addChild(video);
    this.addElement(holder);
    nc.connect(null);

    ns = new NetStream(nc);

    ns.client = {};
    ns.client.onMetaData = ns_onMetaData;
    ns.client.onCuePoint = ns_onCuePoint;

    video.attachNetStream(ns);
    ns.play("Videos/video.mp4");

    ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, statusNet); 
}
```

This works on simulators and on android devices, but not for ios devices. I've seen a couple of similiar questions but they are trying to stream an mp4 from a "http" address where mine is using a local file.

I've been asked to stick to mp4 format, although I have read using an FLV file should work.

> Special considerations for H.264 video in AIR 3.0 for iOS
>   For H.264 video, the iOS APIs for video playback accept only a URL to a file or stream. You cannot pass in a buffer of H264 video data to be decoded.

So do I need to find a new way of playing the video other than netStream or am I best to swap to a different file type?

As a side note Adobe says to write your mp4 URLs like this:

> ("mp4:samples/myvideo.mp4");

My app can't find the file with "mp4:" at the front of the URL.

Comment: This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010572/netstream-http-video-not-playing-on-ios-device

Comment: Thanks, but I've seen this one. He seems to be using a "http:" link not an embeded file. From what I've read it makes a difference.

Comment: It explains pretty much why video is not playing, and also provides a number of solutions. The **StageVideo** one looks quite promising. Did you try them and what was the result?

Comment: I've been asked not to use FLV formatting. I'm struggling to find a good tutorial on stageVideo.

Comment: Oh, look what I've found: *AIR 3 for iOS uses the StageVideo object for H.264 video with hardware decoding, with limited supported for NetStream functionality.* It's from official documentation: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html Do you really need a tutorial on that? The class does not seem to be overly complicated at all.

Comment: Found out why I was struggling with StageVideo. I have a background image and that was overlaying the video as StageVideo is always at the back. :s

Comment: So, you've finally mastered it, I presume? Good.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to play videos that are packaged with your iOS app it's important to ensure you are actually including them when you compile your app.

Untested but something like this should work.

```
var _dFile:File;
var _ns:NetStream;
var _nc:NetConnection;
var _customClient:Object;
var _video:Video;

_customClient = new Object();
_customClient.onMetaData = metaDataHandler;
_nc = new NetConnection();
_nc.connect(null);
_ns = new NetStream(_nc);
_ns.client = _customClient;

//this is the important bit for finding files within the .ipa bundle.
_dFile = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("nameOfYourVideoDirectory/nameOfVideo.mp4");
_ns.play(_dFile.url);

_video = new Video(480, 340);
_video.attachNetStream(_ns);

_ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNSComplete, false, 0, true);

private function metaDataHandler(infoObject:Object):void {
trace("Length of video",infoObject.duration);
}

private function onNSComplete(e:NetStatusEvent):void{
if(e.info.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Empty") {               
//do something
}
}
```

However, I would highly recommend using an ANE to play video on mobile via the native media player. Take a look at Distriqt MediaPlayer ANE.

Comment: Thanks. So With my old code 'ns.play("Videos/video.mp4");' e.info.code would give me Netstream.Play.Start then NetStream.Play.Failed and finally NetStream.Play.Stop. With your code I get NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound. 'File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("Videos/video.mp4");' Is how I've written the path. Looks like it can't find it though.

Comment: Are you sure the videos are being packaged with the .ipa?

Comment: Yes. Managed to get a version working with StageVideo and that finds the file okay. Would still like to know if it was possible with the video component though.