# playing video from directory in flash actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video

I am working with flash professional cs5.5 and actionscript 3.0. I have a project in flash that requires a video to start playing when a button on the swf file is clicked. Problem is I have to play the video without adding it to my library. That is, the video will play directly from the directory it is placed in. In short, the button on the swf file will work as a simple double click on the video. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the Video object to do this. See the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html).

If you're needing to load from a URL, [Adobe has a very good tutorial for that](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d4e.html).

You can apply the exact same principle to loading from a file, since URLs and file paths are handled similarly. [The code on this question should work swimmingly for loading from a file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032141/netstream-video-not-playing-on-ipad)

I hope that helps!